# Hibernate AuditProperty got a new 'alias' argument in 5.1.1.Final

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I notice that when upgrading to Hibernate 5.1.1.Final (from 5.1.0.Final), that a new `String alias`-property was added to `AuditProperty`.

The change seems to have been introduced in [HHH-11025](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11025)

The constructor signature was changed from

`public AuditProperty(PropertyNameGetter propertyNameGetter)`

to

`public AuditProperty(String alias, PropertyNameGetter propertyNameGetter)`

What is this new `alias` argument? I have a legacy application that creates an `AuditProperty` and I'm not sure what I should pass as the `alias` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply pass `null` for the `alias`.

If you take a look at `AuditEntity`, you'll notice several use cases where the old methods that don't deal with aliases, such as the following simply delegate to the new implementation using `null`.

```
public static AuditProperty<RevisionType> revisionType() {
  return revisionType( null );
}

public static AuditProperty<RevisionType> revisionType(String alias) {
  return new AuditProperty<>( alias, new RevisionTypePropertyName() );
}
```